# Change read and write permission of file

Tags: shell, unix, file-permissions

I am trying to change the file permission of a file which is given as command line argument. Please help me out

**The whole problem statement is as follows:**

Write a shell script to change the read and write permission of the file to read,write and execute permission for all.

If file exists display as,

"File Exists!"

else display as,

"File does not Exist"

If file has read and write permission display as,

"File Permission has been changed"

Assume file name is given as command line argument.

**Below is the code that I have tried.**

```
f="$1"
if [ -e $f ]
then echo "File Exists!"

elif [ ! -e $f ]
then 
echo "File does not Exist" && exit
fi

if [ -w $f ] && [ -r $f ]
then 
chmod o-rw $f && echo "File Permission has been changed"
fi
```

**Expected Output:**

Sample Output1:

File Exists!
File Permission has been changed

Sample Output2:

File does not Exist

**Actual Result:**

Failed Test Case 2

File Permission not set

Comment: how do run your script? show ls -l for $1 file. Also there is no need for additional check in elif -e

Comment: do you want to set the permission for all users or for you only? Also can you share the output of ls -l $file output. chmod u+w only gives the owner write permission, it doesn't grant you permission to write to the file. So after running chmod u+w, the file is still not writable by you,

Comment: also in the last if statement you check only for write, not for both write and read

Comment: You say that for the expected output of the second test case it should state that the file does not exist. However, you then say that they failed test case does not set the permissions. If the file should not exist for test case 2, what file are you checking to see if the permissions changed?

It would help if you could provide us with `ls -la` of your working directory and also the actual commands you are using for your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. f="$1"
2. if [ -e $f ] then echo "File Exists!"
3. elif [ ! -e $f ] then  echo "File does not Exist" && exit
4. fi
5. if [-w $f ] && [ -r $f ] then  chmod 777 $f && echo "File Permission
   has been changed"
6. fi

just change --> chmod 777

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it'll work,

```
for f in ${*}
do
if [ -e $f ]; then
    echo "File Exists!"
    if [ -w $f ] && [ -r $f ]; then
        chmod a=rwx $f && echo "File Permission has been changed"
    fi
else
    echo "File does not Exist" && exit
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
f="$1"

for f in ${*}; do
  if [ -e $f ]; then
    echo "File Exists!"

    if [ -w $f ] && [ -r $f ]; then
      chmod a=rwx $f && echo "File Permission has been changed"
    fi
  else
    echo "File does not Exist" && exit
  fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for your answer to this question. If you want to give good quality answer, you could update your code and explain your changes you did. This would help others to undestand it even better.

Answer (score 0):

#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter fIle Name"

read f

for f in $f

do

if [ -e $f ]

then

echo " File Exist...!!! "

if [ -w $f ] && [ -r $f ];
then

```
chmod 777  $f && echo "File Permission has been changed"
```

fi
else

```
echo "File Does not Exist"

echo "Do you want to Re-enter the File Name Press Y or y "
read a;
```

if [ "$a" != "${a#[Yy]}" ];

then

```
   continue

else
   exit
```

fi
fi
done

Answer (score 0):

```
for input in ${*}
do
        checkfile=`test -f ${input}`
        OUT=$?
        if [ $OUT -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo File Exists!
                permission1=`ls -l ${input} | cut -c 2-4 | grep rw`
                OUT=$?
                if [ $OUT -eq 0 ]
                then
                        `chmod 777 ${input}`
                        echo File Permission has been changed
                fi

        else
                echo File does not Exist
        fi
done
```